# Can't find how to stop loop in google script

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, foreach

this is the first time I make a question. I've been trying to search for google script stuff, but I don't quite get where's the community.

So, I'm working on a doc automation project, where my company wants to make out of a spreadsheet some docs. I'm working on the first one, now that difficult, but, I've been trying to make the loop just to generate 1 doc, but it keeps generating docs nonstop, just by manual stop you can make it stop. Here's The code I'm using

```js
function createPIN() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1bwuLoNJQOeuBdLa6Nq-G320J6pkpHt-_aSRdbZ8IqJ8');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1wzhzMRu6HpP0eOnnFl21ZuPaOOZVqFa4');
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sisal');
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (rows[3][1] | rows[3][2]) return;
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy('Def1', destinationFolder);
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    const body = doc.getBody(); 


    body.replaceText('{{Project_Name}}', rows[1][1]);
    Logger.log(rows[1][1])
    body.replaceText('{{Name_of_the_Ejido_owner}}', rows[2][1]);
    Logger.log(rows[2][1])
    body.replaceText('{{Project_Technical_Advisor}}', rows[3][1]);
    Logger.log(rows[3][1])
    body.replaceText('{{Total_Area}}', rows[4][1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Management_Area}}', rows[5][1]);
    
    doc.saveAndClose(); 
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 4).setValue(url) //Manda Url a casilla de link a PIN
  })
}
```

I'm going to attach the spreadsheet I'm working with so you can see the origin of the data. I still can't get the loop to stop. Any suggestions?

[Here is my spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pihg0.png)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your script, how condition do you want to stop the loop by?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. I want to stop the loop after the sheet.getRange(index + 1, 4).setValue(url) line.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have one more question. In your script, what is `if (rows[3][1] | rows[3][2]) return;`? I couldn't understand what you want to do at this line. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. That line I think it´s the problem. I'm kind of new in JS so, I followed the tutorial of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLALWX0_OYs There, the instructor made that to stop the loop I think. I adapted mine from that template, but I quite really understand the logic behind that particular line.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I check your showing URL. But I cannot find `if (rows[3][1] | rows[3][2]) return;`. So I cannot understand what you want to do about this. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it? For example, how condition do you want to stop the loop by? When I could understand this, I thought that I might be able to think of the solution.

Comment: What that YouTube video is showing you is that return will shut down that iteration of the loop but you can't actually stop the  forEach from finishing unless you cancel execution.  If you wish to break out of the loop then use a standard for loop

Comment: @Tanaike: I want the loop to just end after replacing the body of the document, saving it and putting the url on the spread sheet. Forget about that line, it may not be doing anything.

Comment: @Cooper: I think I get your point, i've been reading about that. But I still don't know how to change the statement with a for loop in this particular case, as rows.for() doesn't work like rows.forEach()

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to do this; the problem I got was to understand the use of the forEach loop inside the function: In the tutorial I was seeing, they used the loop to access the whole row, while, in my case, I needed to use independant rows, because the nature of my database. So, I'm going to specify how I solved my problem:

## First of all, I'm going to make this use a more generic one

```
  function createPIN() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Page1');
      const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

      const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy('Def1', destinationFolder);
      const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
      const body = doc.getBody(); 
       
      ## Just forget the loop
      body.replaceText('{{Something}}', rows[x][x]);
      body.replaceText('{{Something2}}', rows[x][y]);
    
      doc.saveAndClose();     
}
```

You just don't need a loop at all, since the objective is to just do a document at a time.